# Garmin app steps, activity and sleep data

Tags: garmin, wearables

I want to develop an app for my own Garmin Vivo active 3 music for this I need to access the live/current data of steps and sleep from my own watch, is there a way I can get an access to this data and create a callback when a certain event is triggered?

Answer (score 1):

**SHORT ANSWER**:
The Garmin Connect IQ API does **NOT** directly provide any information on the number of STEPS or the (amount of) SLEEP.

It does provide the underlying (bare) information from which you could (in principle) calculate these properties. Just have a look at `Toybox::Activity::Info` at https://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/api-docs/

**ANOTHER SUPPORTING QUESTION**:

For clarification: When you say you want to develop an "app": 
Do you mean you want to develop

1. an app running on your Vivo Active 3 or
2. an "app" running on your mobile phone?

In case of (1) you'd need the Garmin Connect IQ (http://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq).
In case of (2), you'd need (1) plus more (which I will answer when you tell me that's what you need).

-cfs

Comment: Christoph, I'm also looking for second option. Can you please share your input if you have work. I need to create saprate app where I can get all activity details from wearable device. I have already integrate Garming connect and intialized sdk. I need to know how to get heartrate and step.
You help will be appreciated. Thanks